# How to align a string variable in Bash

Tags: bash, text-formatting

I'm trying to align a string variable in Bash. This is the desired behaviour.

```
if str1="123"  , then str2="     123"
if str1="1234" , then str2="    1234"
if str1="12345", then str2="   12345"
```

etc.
I've seen how to do it to print with printf, but I need to do it inside the variable without printing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the variable only contains single-byte, single-width characters:

```
printf -v str2 %8s "$str1"
```

If they may contain multi-byte (but still single-width) characters, you can do instead:

```
printf -v str2 %8s%s '' "$str1"
str2=${str2: -8}
```

(note however that that one *truncates* values larger than 8 characters).

Here `bash`'s `printf` builtin command supports `-v` to store the result of `printf` into a variable, but even if it didn't you could use command substitution:

```
str2=$(printf %8s "$str1")
```

Comment: Thank you, very much! I'm trying it now and it will most probably do what I needed.It will help a lot! :)

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, the `-v` makes the `printf` command abstain from printing the result on the screen, instead attributting it to the variable that follows it, is that correct?

Comment: @JairoAlves, yes. See `info bash printf` or `help printf` within `bash` for details.